# Jquery Double clicking on link removing div content

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code to load the content of a DIV ,when some one clicks on a link.

Now,if you click on a link twice,it is removing the content.

Here is the code:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('class');
 if(id == 'first')
    {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');   
      $('a.first').addClass('active');  
    } 
else if(id == 'second')    
     {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');   
      $('a.second').addClass('active');  
    } 

   $('#first').toggle(id == 'first');

   $('#second').toggle(id == 'second');
});​
```

HTML:

```
<a class="first">one</a>
<a class="second">two</a>
<div>
   <li id="first">
       <h2>pen</h2>
       <div>
           <div>parker</div>
       </div>
  </li>
  <li id="second" style="display: none;">
        <h2>car</h2>
        <div>Bugatti</div>
     </div>
   </li>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.active { color: green; }​
```

Comment: is it only for quick double clicks (in that case it could be some race condition), or even if those clicks are separated by tens of seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest workaround using your code is to use a check condition on click callback function:

http://jsfiddle.net/UuFgt/

```
if($(this).is('.active')) return false;
```

Answer (score -1):

you are not "loading" the content, but just displaying it, after it has been hidden (with `display: none`).
So the content is not "removed", it's hidden. Any time you use `removeClass('active');`, you hide the corresponding element.
What is the idea of `toggle()` in your code? I think you are using it wrong. Either you should invert the two (use second for first and first for second), or do it differently.